# How to plot data of unequal size with ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a code segment that looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

uni <- read.csv(filepath_1, header = FALSE)
end_nodes <- read.csv(filepath_2, header = FALSE)

dat <- data.frame(uni, end_nodes) %>%
  gather(var, value)

ggplot(dat, aes(value, fill = var)) + 
  geom_histogram(position="dodge", bins = 10)
```

And this works, and creates a plot like this:

[image]

The problem is that, my two data `uni` and `end_nodes` are not of the same size, and to make them same size I added some dummy 0 values. So, the problem is how can I ignore the 0 values, or is there any way to plot data of unequal size in ggplot2? When I tried to plot them initially I got complain from `data.frame` that they are not of same size, so I added the dummy 0 values. Also, is there any other type of plots, to stack the two data to visualize the distribution, and see how much and where they differ (maybe something like `position = "stack"` or `geom_freqpoly`)? My data is composed of integer  values between 1 and 8, such as `uni = [2,2,1,2,2,1,1,5,3...]`, `end_nodes = [1,6,6,4,3,3,2,2,2...]`.

Comment: What you are asking is not complex. However without any data and reproducible example it is difficult to provide you a solution. Please edit your post with a reproducible example.

Comment: Did you think about using `NA` instead of `0` for missing data ?

Comment: @JRR You can simply sample random integers between 1 and 8, and you have data similar to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of joining by column and then using `gather`, you could just join your two dataframes by row.

```
library(tidyverse)

uni_df <- read.csv(filepath_1, header = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(var = "uni")
end_nodes_df <- read.csv(filepath_2, header = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(var = "end_nodes")

dat <- rbind(uni_df, end_nodes_df)

ggplot(dat, aes(value, fill = var)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge", bins = 10)
```